# Including ex spouses and "had a relationship with" in Gramps

Tags: gramps

I am using Gramps, but it seems to lack places for ex spouses, so children from ex's can't be correctly identified.

Also it lists ongoing marriages as "*had [past tense] a relationship with*" not "*is [present tense] married to*".

Is this possible to do in Gramps?

Comment: Gramps allows you to record multiple spouses for an individual, and assign children to the correct pair of parents -- is that not what you want?

Comment: I don't understand your reference to ex-spouses. While I'm not familiar with GRAMPS, no software that I've seen specifically designates someone as an ex-spouse. Rather, they are recorded as a spouse with - presumably - a divorce event. As @ColeValleyGirl says, the children are then assigned to their correct birth parents and - if necessary and if the software allows - as step children to their step parent.

Comment: Getting the right tense in a report as if the report refers to couples living today, may be problematic in all software as it's designed to record history not current affairs.... Interesting if anyone's software does record someone with "is" rather than "was" for a person with no recorded death.

Comment: @AdrianB38 there definitely are `Divorce` events in Gramps, along with Banns, Engagement, Marriage and Separation.